# Como corregir este error 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy tratando de obtener las coordenadas que están registrados en una base de datos y mostrar marcadores en google maps, pero al momento de correr la aplicación me sale el siguiente error,y me saca de la aplicación, habrá otra manera de poder llamar las coordenadas, he tratado de poner todo lo que esta en el focus zoom dentro del try catch pero no me ha funcionado si me muestra pero todo el mapa completo sin marcadores, no he podido hasta hoy dar con ese detalle, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

**Activity.java**

```
public class Evacuacion_Edo_Mex extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
// Googe Map
private GoogleMap mMap;

// latitude y longitude
private Double latitude = 0.00;
private Double longitude = 0.00;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evacuacion__edo__mex);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.Maps);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //Permission StrictMode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/evacuacionEdoMex.php";

    try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
        location = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("IDlocacion", c.getString("IDlocacion"));
            map.put("latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
            map.put("longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
            map.put("nombre", c.getString("nombre"));
            location.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException E) {
        // Bloque catch generado automáticamente
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Focus y Zoom

    latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("latitude").toString());//linea de error
    longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 17));

    for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("latitude").toString());
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("longitude").toString());
        String name = location.get(i).get("nombre");
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(name);
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
}


private static String getHttpGet(String url) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Descargar OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Error al descargar el resultado");
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.hdez.logishuman.AdminOperacionesAlbergues.CategoriaPEMexico.Evacuacion_Edo_Mex.onMapReady(Evacuacion_Edo_Mex.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da la sensación de que da un error en la generación del JSONArray y por ello nunca crea el objeto location.

```java
 try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url)); 
// Si falla la creación de data va al catch y no se ejecuta la línea de abajo, con lo que location es null
        location = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
```

Después cuando llega a la línea de error location es null y obviamente el acceso a cualquier método de un objeto null da un java.lang.NullPointerException

```java
 latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("latitude").toString());//linea de error
```

Como solución yo creo que sería mejor algo así

```java
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    String url = "https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/evacuacionEdoMex.php";

    try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(c.get("latitude").toString());
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(c.get("longitude").toString());
            if (i == 0) {
                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 17));
            }
            String name = c.get("nombre");
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(name);
            mMap.addMarker(marker);
        }

    } catch (JSONException E) {
        // Bloque catch generado automáticamente
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Que tal amigo, implemente tal como mencionaste en tu respuesta, ya no me sale el error, pero me sale todo el mapa completo si marcadores.

Comment: Con tu respuesta y con otra opcion que implemente con el StringRequest logre lo que necesitaba y ya se vieron los marcadores en maps gracias amigo gynch.